# Autocomplete using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below, is a simple lookup when the user starts typing...

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="question_handset" list="phones" class="form-control">
<datalist id="phones">
<option  data-ng-repeat="ttl in titles" value="{{ttl}}">
</datalist>
```

script:

```
$scope.titles = [ "Comics Action" ,
                "Detective Comics" , "Superman" , "Fantastic Four" , "Amazing Spider-Man" ];
```

My problem is that this only matches on the first word you type.

i.e. I want it to work in a way where you could type: Comics and anything with the word "comics" is shown in the list for example: Detective Comics, Comics Action

I don't want to use jQuery, is there anything that can can be done with the current code to achieve this? Examples would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)? It has a **Typeahead**. Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDnTXlmLnwI8qyPpr0Nr?p=preview) that is provided on their site. I just updated the static array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any angular libs not dependent on other frameworks that do this. But making it yourself is quite doable in angular. Have you seen [this](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/24/typeahead-with-angular/) article? The hardest part is styling the content and aligning it the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Angular module: [ngTagsInput](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTagsInput). I found that it's very powerful and convenient. And of course, completely compatible for an Angular project